# Change Label during AJAX call

Tags: jsf

I want to change the Label of a h:commandLink during AJAX call.

```
<h:commandLink id="submitlink" class="link" value="submit" action="#{mailhandler.testValues}" >
       <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" onevent="handleDisableButton"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function handleDisableButton(data) {
    document.getElementById("form:submitlink").disabled = (data.status != "success");
}
```

I found examples how to do this using Button but in this case I don't know how to implements is for h:commandLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the label to be changed only during the Ajax call:

```
function handleDisableButton(data) {
    data.source.text = 'processing...';
}
```

The initial label will be restored on form update.
If you want it to be permanently changed, bind its value to a backing bean parameter and change it in the action method.